# FOL sentence which is true in a graph G exactly when G has no cycles of length $n $

Tags: logic, graph-theory, problem-solving

> Consider only directed graphs. Show that for each $ n \ge 1$ there is an $L_{\text{graph} } $-sentence $ \phi_n$ which is true in a graph $G $ exactly when $G $ has no cycles of length $n $.

I'm not really familiar with graph theory, so I have no idea how to define such sentences. This question is the first of three in an exercise, and I need this one to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Saying "there is no cycle of length $n$" is saying you can't find vertices $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ so that

$$x_1 E x_2 E x_3 \ldots E x_{n-1} E x_n E x_1$$

where $x E y$ means that $x$ and $y$ are adjacent in the graph.

Do you see how to write this formally in FOL?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: My language contains unary relation symbols $V,E$ ('is vertex', 'is edge'), and binary relation symbols $S,T$ (where $S(v,e)$ means that $v$ is the source node of edge $e$, and $T(v,e)$ = $v$ is the target node of edge $e$). Then, I would say $\neg (\exists x_1,\dots,x_n,e_1,\dots,e_n: V(x_i) \wedge E(e_i) \wedge S(x_1,e_1)\wedge T(x_2,e_1) \wedge S(x_2,e_2)\wedge T(x_3,e_2)\wedge\dots\wedge S(x_n,e_n) \wedge T(x_1,e_n))$

Comment: Maybe, I could define $A$ as $A(x,y) \iff V(x)\wedge V(y) \wedge \exists z(E(z)\wedge S(x,z)\wedge T(y,z))$. This would simplify the notation above. Can I just do that? Use existing relations in my language to define a new one?

Comment: That looks right! And while I can't speak for your professor, in general abbreviations like the one you described are entirely acceptable! They're harmless, and can make keeping track of your formulas _much_ easier.